# Golang slice size keeps on increasing

Tags: go

I'm learning go and am building a little sample console app but have run into a problem that I can't get my head around.

The app I'm building simulates a bus going about it's normal business, picking up and dropping passengers off. The issue I'm having is that a function (letPassengersOff()) seems to be increasing the number of passengers.

I've copied the fun below but you can find the rest of the application here: [BusRoute](https://github.com/donpisci/BusRoute)

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
func letPassengersOff() {
  departing, remaining := []Passenger

  fmt.Println("Number of passengers:", len(b.Passengers))
  for _, value := range b.Passengers {
    if value.ID > 0 {
      if value.EndLocation == b.CurrentStop {
        fmt.Println("Passenger is getting off")
        departing = append(departing, value)
      } else {
        fmt.Println("Passenger is staying on")
        remaining = append(remaining, value)
      }
    }
  }

  fmt.Println("Remaining passengers: ", len(remaining))
  //Setting to nil in the hope that the slice will be cleared
  b.Passengers = nil
  b.Passengers = remaining
  departTheBus(departing)
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile. Which version of Go are you using?

Comment: 1.4.2 I think. That's odd. What errors are you getting? I've tried running go run and go build and it seems ok.

Comment: here: http://pastebin.com/3PQcnVvs

Comment: Should you be clearing `departing` and `remaining`, or explicitly initializing to nil, before processing?

Comment: https://github.com/donpisci/BusRoute/blob/master/src/busroute/bus.go#L27 – this is not how you define methods for the structure. This will never compile and if it does (for your main) it means you're not using the right repository. Shouldn't you have something like `import "github.com/donpisci/BusRoute/src/busroute"` instead of `import "busroute"`? I can smell some import mixups and/or chaos in your GOPATH.

Comment: I've got it compiling with some changes here: http://play.golang.org/p/l4Raj5kZlF

Comment: The code in the question should not add to the number of passengers.  Is this part of a concurrent program?  Are you relying on the print statements to determine that the number of passengers is increasing, or are you checking some other way?

Comment: Thanks @AlexAtNet, I'll get them fixed. Weird that they're not showing up for me though.

Comment: @mpez0, I'll give it a go

Comment: Cheers @weberc2, I'll take a look.

Comment: @tomasz, not sure where you've got the /blob/master from. Was developing locally only initially, with no GitHub repo hence the 'busroute' import. No issues in GOPATH either and it's the only repo on my machine. Your olfactory senses aren't as strong as you think.

Comment: @donpisci you have included link to the repo in your question and I've just navigated to the busroute package in there, exactly where letPassengersOff lives. From your code snippet I can tell your code doesn't compile, but you say it does for you, which indicates some other problem than the original question. I was just pointing to my experience in such the behaviour, when I was importing the wrong package – usually and old one and not the one I was putting the changes in. I have to use my olfactory senses, because I can't see beyond what you've included in your question.

Comment: I can tell you the `busroute` compiled well before the `3f397c` commit _(Unit tests and refactoring)_. Maybe try to run `go build -a` or delete your `pkg` directory? Anyway, this is not relevant to the original question, so I will stop now.

Comment: And btw, [your previous code](https://github.com/donpisci/BusRoute/blob/f73f42b174b75a7bf0d3a028dbd342752f050559/src/busroute/bus.go#L113) didn't work, because you were creating slices with initial size of all passengers in the bus (all zeroed) and then appending more (remaining). I think this is the code you're actually using now when doing `go run`. Your new code would probably fix the issue once you fix the compilation errors. There is no need for `b.Passengers = nil`, just make sure you have the pointer receiver on the method (`func (b *Bus) letPassengersOff()`).

Answer (score 0):

You keep appending to the `remaining` slice. Why not set the slice to the current Passengers. I assume that a "bus" should already have passengers on it?

```
func letPassengersOff(b Bus) {

  remaining := b.Passengers // assume this is a slice
  departing := []Passenger

  fmt.Println("Number of passengers:", len(b.Passengers))
  for i, value := range b.Passengers {
    if value.ID > 0 {
      if value.EndLocation == b.CurrentStop {
        fmt.Println("Passenger is getting off")

        // remove the passenger from remaining and add to departing
        remaining = append(a[:i], a[i+1:]...)
        departing = append(departing, value)

      } else {
        fmt.Println("Passenger is staying on")
        # Do nothing 
      }
    }
  }

  fmt.Println("Remaining passengers: ", len(remaining))
  departTheBus(departing)
```